# Image upload problem in Magento Ver. 1.9.3.7

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, upgrade, image-upload

After upgrading to `Magento Ver. 1.9.3.7`  image upload to product does not work. Buttons are there, but when I click browse files, or upload image, nothing happens. No file upload form, `and no error in console` .
I tried everything, google has offered: cleaning magento cache, reindex data, clear browser cache, try different browser. Nothing helps.
Anyone has an idea, where to start looking for a problem? I guess, Uploader instance is not initialised properly, but console give me no errors.

Comment: Try once to disable all custom modules and file permissions as well.

Answer (score 0):

On a Magento patch **SUPEE-8788** the Flash uploader has been replaced with a JS.

**=> Add in your layout.xml :**

```
    <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/flow.min.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js</file></action>
    </reference>
```

if needed, remove

```
<action method="addJs"><js>mage/adminhtml/flexuploader.js</js></action>
```